# can I use joomla's onAfterRender for a module rather than a plugin?

Tags: joomla, module, joomla1.7

I want to insert some code to Joomla when any page is loaded.

For this I created a module that inserts code.

I am trying to use

```
<?php 
// $Id: helper.php

defined('_JEXEC') or die;
jimport( 'joomla.plugin.plugin' );
jimport( 'joomla.environment.response' );

class modInsertCode
{

    function onAfterRender($params)
    {
            $code = 'some code'; 

            $documentbody = JResponse::getBody();
            $documentbody = str_replace ("</body>", $code." </body>", $documentbody);
            JResponse::setBody($documentbody);

            return true;

    }

}
?>
```

but JResponse::getBody(); returns an empty string. Any ideas, solutions of fixes to this code?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it using a plugin, you won't be able to do it using a module because the HTML response has not been generated by the time the code of the module gets executed.

I hope it helped!

Comment: Alghimo is correct. If you look at the order that the framework is executed, the modules are done before the HTML is built so you are not at the after render step in the process. This must be done with a plugin if you want it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old but for future reference this can be done with jQuery:

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$js = 'jQuery(document).ready( function() { 
           jQuery("#module'.$module->id.'").appendTo(document.body);
       })';
$doc->addScriptDeclaration($js);
```

This is assuming that you have wrapped the content in you module in something like the following, including the module id to support multiple instances of the module.

```
<div id="module<?php echo $module->id; ?>"> Your content </div>
```